# How can I have long waits on Tracewrite, when I haven't run Profiler?

Tags: sql-server-2012, wait-types, sharepoint, trace, waits

I recently setup a SQL Server which is used only ot run a sharepoint Server.
I love to query my wait stats, just to see what we are waiting on.
Most of the wait stats are fine, and I know where they come from and how to improve performance.
When I came to the office today, I saw that I have huge waits on "Tracewrite", but I haven't run any Trace or Profiling session. Is any task/app/anything in Sharepoint able to generate this tracewrite wait? 
Google didn't help me much. Or is Tracewrite also generated by some other task?

I am on SQL Server 2014 / Sharepoint 2013 / Windows 2012

A check on:

```
SELECT * FROM sys.traces
```

shows that some log is generated in the following path:

\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.SQLSP2013\MSSQL\Log

The `event count of 83321` sounds a bit high to me.

This server runs just for some days.

Comment: Do you have any third part tools monitoring your server?

Comment: It could be the default trace what traces are registered in sys.traces SELECT * FROM sys.traces

Comment: no, no 3rd party tools which can enable a trace, besides Sharepoint? I am not sure what sharepoint can do

Comment: @Spörri I added my trace, there are 3 more with no relevant data

Comment: You can find out whose traces they are from the default trace (one of them is likely the default trace - did you look at all of the columns in sys.traces?) : http://sqlblog.com/blogs/jonathan_kehayias/archive/2010/12/29/learn-who-started-that-trace-with-the-default-trace.aspx

Comment: Let us know if you get a solution. I am having the same issue. I collected wait stats for over a dozen SQL Servers. One of them is SharePoint. The SharePoint server was the one server having TRACEWRITE waits (I only collect the top ten) and its Wait_S was the highest of all waits for all servers 10 fold! That is pretty darn significant! I used the link Aaron supplied to find server side traces being created by the SPT_Farm user several times a second all day every day from several client servers!